# Is the word Hindu mentioned in any Sanatan scriptures?

Tags: vedas, puranas, culture, rig-veda

Is the word 'Hindu' mentioned in any Sanatan scriptures?

Because there is lot said and lot to be said on the word Hindu. I went through different old literature but did not find the word Hindu.

Answer (score -1):

No.
Ancient Persians/Greeks referred to people living beyond Sindhu (Indus) river as Sindhus, which over time, morphed into 'Hindu'.

Comment: Linking wikipedia is not a reliable source. You should cite some authoritative sources.

Comment: Actually the word "Hindu" is a derogatory word and it is mentioned by Iranian traveller and Polymath Al'Biruni in his notes when he came to India with Khilji. The word is a geographical description and not a religious one. The word means thief 'dog,' 'low life', 'slave', defeated in the persian language.

Comment: @pankajdoharey - lol.. that's not the meaning of the word. that might be their mindset. like how we associate Muslims as terrorists. It doesn't mean the word Muslim itself means terrorist.

Comment: @mar No, According to the Persian dictionary Lughat e' Kishori it quite literally means what i said.  It is not by association, it is the meaning they have written in the dictionary.

Comment: @pankajdoharey - post link to persian-english dictionary which has your meaning

Comment: @mar Here read it yourself https://archive.org/details/lughaatikishori/mode/2up
this is what you are looking for هندو